# RedirectToRoute in MVC Not Redirecting Using Default Route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect

When I try to redirect using RedirectToRoute() it is not working for default route for a particular case. As per the RouteConfig.cs the priority is for Cuisine whenever it identifies a url with cuisine in it. I want to use default route in a particular scenario while accessing the cuisine controller. It should redirect to **Redirect** action in the cuisine controller. Is it possible?.

**The code snippet:**

RouteConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Cuisine", 
            "cuisine/{name}",
            new { controller = "Cuisine", action = "Search", name = UrlParameter.Optional });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

CuisineController.cs

```
 public class CuisineController : Controller
{
    // GET: Cuisine
    public ActionResult Search(string name)
    {
        return RedirectToRoute("Default", new { controller = "Cuisine", action = "Redirect" });
    }

    public ActionResult Redirect()
    {
        return Content("Restaurant Closed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirect is generated correctly the problem you have is that:
http://app.com/cuisine/redirect
matches both rules and:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            "Cuisine", 
            "cuisine/{name}",
            new { controller = "Cuisine", action = "Search", name = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

is first in the Route Table so it's the one used.
You can simply fix it by adding additional route config for redirect before `Cuisine` one:

```
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
              "Cuisine-redirect",
              "cuisine/redirect",
              new { controller = "Cuisine", action = "Redirect"});
    routes.MapRoute(
               "Cuisine",
               "cuisine/{name}",
               new { controller = "Cuisine", action = "Search", name = UrlParameter.Optional });

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

This way `Cuisine-redirect` route will be matched and executed first.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. The MapRoute that you have added is kind of completely hard coded. It will not work if there is an additional action called RedirectX. Is there any way I can force the Default Route?

Comment: Yes but this would require you to change the redirection url. 
You can't use http://appurl.com/cuisine/redirect because this will be matched to your `Cuisine` route, you can use http://appurl.com/cuisine/name/redirect or anything with additional route parameter and use Attribute Routing to accomodate additional parameter. Or simply change your 'Cuisine' route to point to http://appurl.com/cuisine/search/name this way you will get rid of the problem altogether (if you can of course)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below Code instead of your code

In RedirectRoute you can able to redirect by using the below code also

By giving the action name in first and controller name following. 
please look deeply in bold area.

```
 public class CuisineController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Search(string name)
   {
      return RedirectToRoute(**"Redirect", "Cuisine"**);
   }

   public ActionResult Redirect()
   {
      return Content("Restaurant Closed");
   }
}
```